# Load JSON value into a dataTables textarea field

Tags: jquery, json, ajax, datatables, textarea

I have a textarea dynamically created each time the page loads like below.

```
"aoColumnDefs": [
            {
                "aTargets": [4],
                "createdCell": function (td, cellData, rowData, row, col) {
                    $(td).html('<textarea name="playerProfile" class="playerIfo" spellcheck="true" rows="2" cols="60"> </textarea>  ');

                }
            }
```

I have a JSON that I am reading and then storing into an array. I also have a global variable named userProfile and assigning it the value of the JSON field. I have tried experimenting all sorts of ways to dynamically load the field in the textfield after pushing it into my array, but that just doesn't seem to work. I can see the status of each userProfile however, I just can't seem to get into the textarea. Am not seeing any nulls nor errors in the console, so am concluding that my ways of loading into the textarea are not correct. Code below.

```
function getPlayerData() {
    $.ajax({
        url: urlToUse,
        dataType: 'json',
        type: 'GET',
    }).done(function (response) {
        renderTeamPlayerData(response);
    });
}
    function renderTeamPlayerData(result){ 
          var DataArray = [];
          var monthNames = ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun",
          "Jul", "Aug", "Sept", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"
          ];
         $.each(result.players, function () {
            userProfile = this.userProfile;
            console.log("starting player profile -> " + userProfile );
            var rawDate = new Date(this.contractUntil);
            var datePretty = monthNames[rawDate.getMonth()] + ", " + (rawDate.getDate()) 
            + " " + rawDate.getFullYear();
            DataArray.push([this.name,
                            this.nationality,
                            this.position,
                            userProfile,
                            datePretty
            ]);
            console.log("player profile -> " + userProfile );
            $(this).closest('tr').find('.playerIfo').text(userProfile );
            //$(this).closest('tr').find('.playerIfo').val(userProfile );
            console.log("player profile after -> " + userProfile );
            //$(this).closest('table tr>td').find('textarea').val(userProfile);
            //$(".playerIfo").text(userProfile);
            //$('textarea[name=playerProfile]').innerHTML =userProfile ;
        });
        $('#playerTable').dataTable().fnAddData(DataArray);
        $('#playerTable').dataTable().fnAdjustColumnSizing();
    }
```

Could someone show me a way to load a JSON field (that I have stored in an array) dynamically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are doing it backwards. You are trying to insert `userProfile` before the table elements is created, i.e before `fnAddData(DataArray)`.

Since `userProfile` is present in data there is no need for injecting it by code. Remove `$(this).closest('tr').find('.playerIfo').text(userProfile );` and use the [**`render()`**](https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.render) callback instead of `createdCell()` :

```
"aoColumnDefs": [{
   "aTargets": [4],
   "render": function(data, type, full, meta) {
     if (type == 'display') {
       return '<textarea name="playerProfile" class="playerIfo" spellcheck="true" rows="2" cols="60">'
            + data 
            + '</textarea>';
     }
     return data
   } 
}]
```